# ngx-bootstrap datepicker problem to fix it to input field

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I tried to set this datepicker on dialog, but if dialog open scrolled down popup with dates stays up, not go down with input field from where i want to choose it.
Is there any way to fix it to input?
p.s. Probably the problem is somewhere in CSS but I don't know how to make it sticked to input field, also I will try to put code latter, Thanks

Comment: do you get an errors or warnings (e.g. in browser console)
could you add an example via plunkr or stackblitz?
or at least some code

Comment: No, there is no any error, it just stays fixed somewhere up, when dialog is down opened. Everything other works good except that problem. I worked everything from this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmz1L_Azrjk

Comment: but you wrote the code yourself, I assume.
some posted code or even better a plunkr/stackblitz would help us to better help you

Comment: I tried to put code but it doesn't allow me to do it, I don't know why, or how to do it correctly.

Comment: go to this link for edit your question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with datepickers on my modals. In my case, the problem was fixed by setting the modal body div as the container of the datepicker (When container is not set, body is the default value).

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" bsDatepicker [container]="'.modal-body'"/>
```

Ngx-bootrap doc: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#bs-datepicker-component